# how to fix file .json not found when it is there

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I am trying here to consume the data from a json file:
DATA.json

```
[

{"Label"
        
        :"USA",
        "Adress":"This is the us",
        "Lat":"36.9628066",
        "Lng":"-122.0194722"
},
{ "Label"  :"USA",
         "Address":"2020",
          "Lat":"36.9628066", 
          "Lng":"-122.0194722" }

]
```

Then applying it in my Mainclass:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;


namespace Orbage
{
    

class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street

            };
            // ...
            Content = customMap;

            var json = File.ReadAllText("File.json");
            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<File>>(json);
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = "Xamarin",

                    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                };



                customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };

                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

But when I put the file in there it says that it doesn't exist.
Error:
FilenotfoundException
Whats the fix for this.
I tried:
Changing the location of the file.
Its name
Instead of E:/-/- i even wrote file.json but I still get the same error.
Thanks alot!

Comment: Use ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDirs(null) to get the list of internal and external directories of your app and prepend it to the file name.

Comment: Please can you explain with a slight of code.. I didn't understand what u meant by prepend it to the file name.

Comment: what's the full path of the json file and full path of Mainclass?

Comment: its this C:\Users\----\source\repos\-----\-----\------\DATA.json

Comment: which project did you add the file to?

Comment: This one. I added it in this one

Comment: Could it work with the below method ?

Comment: No. It did not work with the below method.

Comment: @Jason I added it to my current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the method below:

Put your `File.json` to your PCL project,and set its `Build Action` to `EmbeddedResource`.

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MapPage)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Orbage.File.json");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
     {
       text = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
```

Comment: @ItsRaptorman  Replace  `var json = File.ReadAllText("File.json");`

Comment: Yes I did do that. But  in this  var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json);  When I did replace that the json and DATA have errors.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman What error ? Let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219533/11).

Answer (score 2):

Its better before reading the file, put check whether file exists in the location or not.

```
if (File.Exists("File.Json"))
```

With this you would become to know that your given path is correct or not.